# Does direction of angle (clockwise/ anticlockwise) matters in trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, angle, ratio

In a Cartesian coordinate system, we draw a unit radius arc with centre at origin in anticlockwise direction. Let the angle substended by this arc be $\theta$. Now if we measure this same $\theta$ in clockwise direction, would all its trigonometric ratios be same? Why? Why not?

Comment: $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(-\theta) = \cos(\theta)$.  The other trig functions can be obtained from these.  So going clockwise (rather than anti-clockwise) can change the sign of a trigonometric function, but not the magnitude.

Comment: What do you mean by "measue this same \theta in clockwise direction"? The arc and the angle is the same. Just as a line segment has the same length no matter how you measure it.